# Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Eu estava fazendo um app e em um dado momento me deparei com o erro `Default Activity not found`. Tentei desfazer as alterações e o erro persistiu .Tentando soluciona-lo notei que todos os arquivos `.xml` do projeto apresentam um erro no campo `tools:context=` .

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity android:name=".activity.RequisicoesActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.MapsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CadastroActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_cadastro"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_login"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.MapsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CadastroActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_cadastro"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_login"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
</application>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Retire a seguinte parte do arquivo xml da activity ".activity" e deixe desta forma:

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: o erro persiste.Agadeço a tentativa

Comment: Faça o seguinte: Comece digitando no xml tools:context=".", pare e deixe que o Android Studio indique a qual activity você quer atrelar o seu xml. Se o android studio não apontar nenhuma activity, reinicie o android studio limpando o cache e faça o mesmo procedimento.

Comment: muito obrigado meu Nobre .O erro do `.xml` foi resolvido o codigo ficou assim `tools:context="marcelootaviodeandrade.turbam.com.activity.MainActivity">
` porem o erro **Default Activity not found** persiste.

Comment: Sua estrutura está app/src/main/java/.../activity/MainActivity.java? Você já tentou `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`?